# Pseint error: Lin 8 (inst 1): ERROR 303: Subindice (0) fuera de rango (1...250) ...dentro del subproceso CARGARARREGLOS, invocado desde la línea 48

Tags: pseint

```
SubProceso CargarArreglos(nombres, documentos, promedios, CE_NOM, CE_DOC, CE_PROM, CANT)
    Definir NOM Como cadena
    Definir DOCU Como Entero
    Definir PROME Como Real
    
    Mientras CE_NOM < CANT Hacer
        ObtenerDatos(NOM, DOCU, PROME)
        nombres[CE_NOM] <- NOM
        documentos[CE_NOM] <- DOCU
        promedios[CE_NOM] <- PROME
        CE_NOM <- CE_NOM + 1
        CE_DOC <- CE_DOC + 1
        CE_PROM <- CE_PROM + 1
    FinMientras
FinsubProceso

SubProceso ObtenerDatos(N, D, P)
    Escribir "Ingrese el nombre del alumno"
    Leer N
    Escribir "Ingrese el DNI del alumno"
    Leer D
    Escribir "Ingrese el promedio academico del alumno"
    Leer P
FinSubProceso

Algoritmo  ListadoAlumnosPromedio
    Definir MAX_ALUMNOS, CANT, CE_NOM, CE_DOC, CE_PROM Como Entero
    Definir sumaPromedios, promedioGeneral Como Real
    
    sumaPromedios <- 0
    MAX_ALUMNOS <- 250
    Dimension nombres[MAX_ALUMNOS]
    Dimension documentos[MAX_ALUMNOS]
    Dimension promedios[MAX_ALUMNOS]
    
    Escribir "Ingrese la cantidad de alumnos que desea cargar al sistema"
    Leer CANT
    
    Mientras CANT > MAX_ALUMNOS o CANT <= 0 Hacer
        Escribir "El numero ingresado no es valido, por favor ingrese un numero mayor a 0 y menor o igual a 250"
        Leer CANT
    FinMientras
    
    CE_NOM <- 0
    CE_DOC <- 0
    CE_PROM <- 0
    
    CargarArreglos(nombres, documentos, promedios, CE_NOM, CE_DOC, CE_PROM, CANT)
    
    Para i = 0 Hasta CANT - 1 Hacer
        sumaPromedios <- sumaPromedios + promedios[i]
    FinPara
    
    promedioGeneral <- sumaPromedios / CANT
    
    Escribir "Listado de alumnos con promedio mayor o igual al promedio general:", promedioGeneral
    
    Para i = 0 Hasta CANT - 1 Hacer
        Si promedios[i] >= promedioGeneral Entonces
            Escribir "Nombre:", nombres[i]
            Escribir "Documento:", documentos[i]
            Escribir "Promedio académico:", promedios[i]
            Escribir "-----"
        Fin Si
    FinPara
    
FinAlgoritmo
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu código tenía varios problemines, le hice algunos cambios...

```
   /// eliminé las variables **CE_DOC, CE_PROM** ya que estaban de adorno, 
   /// renombre **CE_NOM** porque creo que ese nombre genera confusión.
SubProceso CargarArreglos(nombres, documentos, promedios, CANT)
    Definir NOM Como cadena 
    Definir DOCU Como Entero
    Definir POS Como Entero
    Definir PROME Como Real
    
       /// acá esta el problema más grave, los arreglos comienzan en "1", de ahi
       /// los mensajes de error que recibías
    POS <- 1
    Mientras  POS <= CANT Hacer

           /// elimine una función, ya que resuelto el problema de los indices
           /// en los arreglos, sin bien no arrojaba errores, devolvía todo vacío
        Escribir "Ingrese el nombre del alumno"
        Leer NOM
        Escribir "Ingrese el DNI del alumno"
        Leer DOCU
        Escribir "Ingrese el promedio academico del alumno"
        Leer PROME
        nombres[ POS ] <- NOM
        documentos[ POS ] <- DOCU
        promedios[ POS ] <- PROME
        POS  <-  POS  + 1
    FinMientras
FinsubProceso

Algoritmo  ListadoAlumnosPromedio
    Definir MAX_ALUMNOS, CANT, CE_NOM Como Entero
    Definir sumaPromedios, promedioGeneral Como Real
    
    sumaPromedios <- 0
    MAX_ALUMNOS <- 250
    Dimension nombres[MAX_ALUMNOS]
    Dimension documentos[MAX_ALUMNOS]
    Dimension promedios[MAX_ALUMNOS]
    
    Escribir "Ingrese la cantidad de alumnos que desea cargar al sistema"
    Leer CANT
    
    Mientras CANT > MAX_ALUMNOS o CANT <= 0 Hacer
        Escribir "El numero ingresado no es valido, por favor ingrese un numero mayor a 0 y menor o igual a 250"
        Leer CANT
    FinMientras 
    
    CargarArreglos(nombres, documentos, promedios, CANT)

       /// cambié i = 0 por i = 1 por el mismo motivo
    Para i = 1 Hasta CANT Hacer
        sumaPromedios <- sumaPromedios + promedios[i]
    FinPara
    
    promedioGeneral <- sumaPromedios / CANT
    
    Escribir "Listado de alumnos con promedio mayor o igual al promedio general:", promedioGeneral

       /// repetimos cambio
    Para i = 1 Hasta CANT Hacer
        Si promedios[i] >= promedioGeneral Entonces
            Escribir "Nombre:", nombres[i]
            Escribir "Documento:", documentos[i]
            Escribir "Promedio académico:", promedios[i]
            Escribir "-----"
        Fin Si
    FinPara
    
FinAlgoritmo
```